# Android, Maven and Jackson

Tags: android, maven, jackson, android-testing, android-maven-plugin

I'm trying to take Jackson into use in my Android app project. Everything else works nice but running tests in CI through Maven fail, if I run the same test from Eclipse it works but then I'm not using Maven POM files i.e. I'm not importing the project as Maven project, instead I have copied jackson JAR's into libs -folder. 
Jackson dependency is added to application POM like this:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

The error I'm getting from Jenkins looks like this:

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation

and Logcat prints the following:

```
Class resolved by unexpected DEX:
LmyClass;(0x41345f78):0x190e58 ref [Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper;] Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper;(0x41345f78):0x1a08b0
(LmyClass; had used a different Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper; during pre-verification)
```

This is caused the following line in my code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

The test I'm running is Android InstrumentationTestCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=142). One solution is to add the following to your dependency:

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be known problem and it is also documented in maven-android-plugin pages (https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/AutomateAndroidTestProject?ts=1302196581&updated=AutomateAndroidTestProject).